# How to quickly and efficiently check if an image is mostly background?

Tags: python, image, opencv, machine-learning, image-processing

I have gigapixel sized whole slide images of cancer tissue that I'm sampling patches from to train a CNN.This is what one of them looks like.

[image]

Right now, I'm using the code below to try and filter out background patches that are more than 30% blank but it doesn't seem to be working.

```
   i = random.randint(0, x - patch_size/(2**level))
   j = random.randint(0, y - patch_size/(2**level))
   grey = cv2.cvtColor(img[j:j+patch_size/(2**level), i:i+patch_size/(2**level)], cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)    
   ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(grey, 80, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
   if numpy.sum(thresh <= 10) >= 0.3*(patch_size**2):
       arr.append((i, j))
```

Many of the patches I'm generating are still blank and I believe it might be because of the off-white sections of the image not being filtered out. In any case, I don't believe my method of converting the patch to greyscale and then thresholding to count white pixels is all that efficient. I had the thought of maybe comparing by filesize as I noticed that all the blank images have low filesizes but saving a patch, calculating the filesize, and then deleting it doesn't seem all that efficient either. Any thoughts on a fast and efficient way to filter out the non-tissue patches?

EDIT: Just some additional information I posted in the comments.
Anything that isn't pink or purple is background. My patches are 256x256 in images that can be over 1,000,000x1,000,000. I select patches by randomly generating coordinate points representing the top left corner of a patch within the downsampled width and height, checking to see if the patch is mostly tissue, and then saving the coordinates to an array. I've got contours that point out regions of interest but my code for selecting patches within them works fine. I just need to select areas outside the ROIs that have normal tissue and are not mostly blank space

Comment: How big are the patches? How do you select a patch? If I assume you crop out the patch, then you can test the standard deviation value against some threshold. If too low, the image is a flat color and throw it out. If it is high enough, then you have texture variation and likely image content.

Comment: how do you define "background"? Will the definition work for all of yozr images?

Comment: Anything that isn't pink or purple is background. My patches are 256x256 in images that can be over 1,000,000x1,000,000.  I select patches by randomly generating coordinate points representing the top left corner of a patch within the downsampled width and height, checking to see if the patch is mostly tissue, and then saving the coordinates to an array. I've got contours that point out regions of interest but my code for selecting patches within them works fine. I just need to select areas outside the ROIs that have normal tissue and are not mostly blank space.

Comment: Try using OpenCV's `meanStdDev()` and checking if the standard deviation is low - that means that nothing changes much in the 256x256 area you are looking at, so it is flat and without variation.

Comment: I tried this, but unfortunately now I'm only picking up the black lines along the edges. I don't have any guarantee how far into the image those lines are nor where the actual tissue could be in the image so I can't just cut out the edges of the image.

Comment: You can try using dynamic thresholding techniques such as Otsu's threshold or adaptive thresholding the image so you don't have to calculate the threshold value. From here you could find the non zero pixels with `np.nonzero` then use this to determine if the background is empty

Answer (score 2):

An approach is to Otsu's threshold so the values are either `255` for white or `0` for black then apply `cv2.countNonZero()`. The function will count all non-white pixels, if this value is less than a predetermined threshold (half the image area) then it is mostly blank space background. Here's the thresholded image

[image]

We calculate the pixel ratio of white to black pixels then use this ratio to determine the result using a minimum background threshold

```
Pixel ratio: 9.88%
Mostly Background
```

Code

```
import cv2

image = cv2.imread('1.png')
h, w, _ = image.shape
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_OTSU + cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)[1]

pixels = cv2.countNonZero(thresh)
ratio = (pixels/(h * w)) * 100
print('Pixel ratio: {:.2f}%'.format(ratio))

if ratio < 50:
    print('Mostly Background')
else:
    print('Not Mostly Background')

cv2.imshow('thresh', thresh)
cv2.waitKey()
```